# Can't make export of code from org

Tags: org-export

Emacs 27.050
Windows 10

Hello.

I want to export python code block from my org file to the file.

When executing block there is the following result:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :session  :results output :exports code :file example.py
print ("foo"+ "bar")
#+END_SRC

Here is what is written to the file example.py
==> foobar
```

How can I export source code to the file?

Comment: Have a look at [tangling](https://orgmode.org/manual/Extracting-Source-Code.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the help of @Juancho I have found the answer to this question.
It was solved with the help of `org-babel-tangle (C-c C-v t)`, with such header:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :tangle example.py
print ("foo"+ "bar")
#+END_SRC
```